# Theta bound of the following function

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis

Suppose the function $f(n)$ is defined as the number of $\ast$ printed in the following code

```
for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
    for(int j = i; j<n; j++) {
        for(int k = j + 200; k<2n; k++) {
            for( int r = k^2; r<n; r++) {
                print(*);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect the answer is $\Theta(n^{2.5})$, by running the code at $n=5000$ and $n=50000$, but I do not have a rigid proof.

Can anyone enlighten me? Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Answer (score 1):

First, note that  we print a * for every tuple $(i,j,k,r)$ such that
$0 \leq  i \leq j \leq k-200 \leq \sqrt{r}-200\leq \sqrt{n}-200$

For every $i$ and $j$ there are at most $(\sqrt{n}-200)$ options, for $k$ it is $\sqrt{n}$ and for $r$ it is $n$. Thus the upper bound for the number of * is $(\sqrt{n}-200)\cdot (\sqrt{n}-200) \cdot \sqrt{n} \cdot  n\in O(n^{2.5})$.

To compute the lower bound, we can take $i$'s in the range between $0$ and $\frac{\sqrt{0.5n}-200}{2}$, $j's$  between $\frac{\sqrt{0.5n}-200}{2}+1$ and $\sqrt{0.5n}$, $k$'s between $\sqrt{0.5n}+1$ and $\sqrt{0.75n}$, and finally, $r's$ between $0.75n+1$ to $n$. Thus the number of options for a tuple $(i,j,k,r)$ is more than $(\frac{\sqrt{0.5n}-200}{2})^2 \cdot (\sqrt{0.75n}-\sqrt{0.5n})\cdot 0.25n \in \Omega(n^{2.5})$.

Thus the answer is $\Theta(n^{2.5})$

Comment: Hi, and thanks for taking the time to write up an answer! Note that we have a [reference question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis) that explains in detail how to approach problems such as the OP's, so you may want to invest your energy on less routine questions in the future.